# importing csv file to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I'm using MySQL with php. Through a php script i'm trying to import a csv file with the following query

```
    LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$file'
    INTO TABLE userstable
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES (name, univ, mobile);
```

I'm successfully able to import the file in to the database tables but i'm able to see 
hidden formatting symbols (as in word, powerpoint, etc..) in all the cells under the last column i.e mobile.

How to avoid those from inserting in the table

Comment: shocking? Why is it shocking to see mysql slurping in what's in the file? I'd be more shocked if mysql became telepathic and could read your mind and figure out how to skip that data you don't want on its own.

Comment: @Marc B sorry for that. can you tell be how to skip those?

Comment: option 1 clean the csv file, option 2 clean the db after import, option 3 custom import that cleans the data on import, option 4 'fix' what ever creates the csv file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be DOS line endings.
Try it with

```
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're going to have to use regular expressions to filter the data before it is saved. If I remember correctly, most of that formatting is standardized, so it should be easy to find and eliminate before adding it to your dB. - lee